# VXML Value to PHP Variable

Tags: php, forms, variables, vxml

I have a single page VXML Script, I have passed dialed DTMF to a form and that works fine.

But I would also like to pass the value into a PHP Variable.

Is that possible ?

```
<prompt> <value expr="Digits"/> </prompt>
```

This works but how to I assign 'Digits' to $test in PHP ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In VoiceXML the process of passing variables into a server side script is commonly done using one of three tags (`<submit>`, `<subdialog>` or `<data>`).  All three of these support a standard convention of providing a URL, HTTP method (get or post) and a namelist of variables that will be sent to the web server.

Assuming you have a fairly simple VoiceXML script:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<vxml version="2.1">
  <form>
    <field name="Digits" type="digits">
      <prompt>Please enter some digits.</prompt>
      <filled>
        <prompt>You entered: <value expr="Digits"/></prompt>
        <submit next="path/to/script.php" method="post" namelist="Digits"/>
      </filled>
    </field>
  </form>
</vxml>
```

You would then access the variables in VoiceXML using the normal $_POST variable:

```
<?php
  $test = $_POST['Digits'];
  echo("<?vxml version=\"1.0\"?>\n");
?>
<vxml version="2.1">
  <form>
    <block>
      <prompt>You posted: <?=htmlspecialchars($test)?>.</prompt>
    </block>
  </form>
</vxml>
```

This architecture allows VoiceXML to operate is a traditional web server / web browser with HTTP POST and response.  You can also use the `<data>` tag to more closely mimic modern AJAX style applications where you can POST name/value pairs and get back arbitrary XML documents that can be accessed using the normal Javascript DOM.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I was hoping to use `<submit next="#newform" namelist="Digits">` and pass the value to a new form and then parse that into a PHP Variable.

Is that possible ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  When you use a hash (#newform) you are doing a local jump within the script.  Out of curiosity why do you need to get this variable into a remote PHP variable only to jump to a local form item?

Comment: The value entered is a number and I'll like to use it as a key to an array.

eg: `echo $new[$test];`